# Python Lists vs Arrays Speed

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, numpy

I am trying to show that a iterating over a NumPy array is faster than a list. I'm doing this by creating a zero array and looping over it to increment each element, and by building a list of zeros with .append() and then looping over it a second time to increment each element. It seems to me that the array should certainly be faster here, but it's just about 2x slower! My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import time

N = 10000

# Check array
start = time.time()
arr = np.zeros(N, dtype = int)
for x in range(N):
    arr[x] += 1
end = time.time()

print("Array op took {} seconds".format(end - start))

# Check list
start = time.time()
ls = []
for x in range(N):
    ls.append(0)

for element in ls:
    element += 1

end = time.time()

print("List op took {} seconds".format(end - start))
```

What is going wrong here? Am I just wrong in thinking that a NumPy array should be faster?

To clarify w.r.t. the duplicate flag, the other question didn't discuss traversal of a NumPy array, just its repeated instantiation. It was also about small NumPy arrays, rather than large ones.

Comment: Never use a `for` loop on a NumPy array if you can help it!

Comment: I think `numpy`'s arrays are slower because they've got lots of methods that can be applied to them and more internal data

Comment: @ajcr, this did it! Silly me. If you want to change this to an answer I could accept it.